# How to attach an object to an event in C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, pixelsense

I defined the following DataTemplate for a LibraryContainer:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContainerItemTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Margin="3">
                    <s:SurfaceTextBox IsReadOnly="True" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=name}" Padding="3"/>
                </Border>
                <s:SurfaceButton Content="Expand" Click="SourceFilePressed"></s:SurfaceButton>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

The SourceFilePressed is the following:

```
 private void SourceFilePressed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Logging.Logger.getInstance().log(sender.ToString());
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

In the method SourceFilePressed who can I get the object that is binded to the SurfaceTextBox that is in the same grid as the pressed button? Can I somehow in the DataTemplate attach this object to the Click-Event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I parsed your question correctly, I think you could do this:

```
private void SourceFilePressed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
}
```

To explain: the sender is the source of the event, so it's the `SurfaceButton`. It is a `FrameworkElement` and thus has a `DataContext` property. The `DataContext` is an inherited property, so unless you set it explicitly on the `SurfaceButton`, it will inherit it's `DataContext` from its parent (the `Grid`). The `DataTemplate`'s `DataContext` is the data item it is templating, so you can see that the `SurfaceButton` will have that same object as its `DataContext`.